# Inserting an element before each element of a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm looking to insert a constant element before each of the existing element of a list, i.e. go from:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

to:

```
['a', 'foo', 'a', 'bar', 'a', 'baz']
```

I've tried using list comprehensions but the best thing I can achieve is an array of arrays using this statement:

```
[['a', elt] for elt in stuff]
```

Which results in this:

```
[['a', 'foo'], ['a', 'bar'], ['a', 'baz']]
```

So not exactly what I want. Can it be achieved using list comprehension? Just in case it matters, I'm using Python 3.5.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add another loop:

```
[v for elt in stuff for v in ('a', elt)]
```

or use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) together with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`itertools.repeat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) if you need an iterable version rather than a full list:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat
try:
    # Python 3 version (itertools.izip)
    from future_builtins import zip
except ImportError:
    # No import needed in Python 3

it = chain.from_iterable(zip(repeat('a'), stuff))
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple generator function works nicely here too:

```
def add_between(iterable, const):
    # TODO: think of a better name ... :-)
    for item in iterable:
        yield const
        yield item

list(add_between(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 'a')
```

This lets you avoid a nested list-comprehension and is quite straight-forward to read and understand at the cost of being *slightly* more verbose.

Answer (score 2):

You already have

```
   l =  [['a', 'foo'], ['a', 'bar], ['a', 'baz']]
```

You can flatten it using

```
[item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

this even works for arbitrary length nested list.